# How to access existing dict key inside a for loop without creating a new key?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, merge

I have a list of dictionaries like so

```
names = [{'id':1, 'name': 'Alice', 'dep_name':'Pammy', 'is_dep_minor':True, 'is_insured':False},
          {'id':2, 'name': 'Alice', 'dep_name':'Trudyl', 'is_dep_minor':False, 'is_insured':True},
          {'id':3, 'name': 'Bob', 'dep_name':'Charlie', 'is_dep_minor':True, 'is_insured':True},]
```

I want to create a new unified dictionary with new properties that will be populated later. I am planning to eliminate the need to have two dicts for Alice when it can be nested inside. This is what I have so far.

```
results = []
for name in names:
    newdict = defaultdict(dict)
    newdict[name[name]]["NEWKEY"] = None # to be filled in later
    newdict[name[name]]["ANOTHERKEY"] = None # to be filled in later

    innerdict = defaultdict(dict)
    innerdict["dep_name"]["is_minor"] = name["is_dep_minor"]
    innerdict["dep_name"]["is_insured"] = name["is_insured"]

    newdict[name[name]]["DEPENDENTS"] = innerdict
    results.append(newdict)
```

This gives me

```
[
  {
    "Alice" : {
      "NEWKEY" : None,
      "ANOTHERKEY" : None,
      "DEPENDENTS" : {
          "Pammy" : {
              "is_minor" : True,
              "is_insured" : False
           }
      }
   }
  },
  {
    "Alice" : {
      "NEWKEY" : None,
      "ANOTHERKEY" : None,
      "DEPENDENTS" : {
          "Trudy" : {
              "is_minor" : False,
              "is_insured" : True
           }
       }
    }
  },
  # and the list goes on
]
```

What I'm aiming for is

```
  {
    "Alice" : {
      "NEWKEY" : None,
      "ANOTHERKEY" : None,
      "DEPENDENTS" : {
          "Pammy" : {
              "is_minor" : True,
              "is_insured" : False
           },
           "Trudy" : {
              "is_minor" : False,
              "is_insured" : True
           }
       }
    }
  },
```

Can someone help me out with this? Thanks in Advance

Comment: names is a variable

Comment: That was a type sorry. Corrected.The issue i'm facing is different. Can you please remove the -1 vote so i can get some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I did it like so

```
results = {}

def create_dict():
    newdict = {}
    newdict["NEWKEY"] = None # to be filled in later
    newdict["ANOTHERKEY"] = None # to be filled in later

    innerdict = defaultdict(dict)
    innerdict["dep_name"]["is_minor"] = name["is_dep_minor"]
    innerdict["dep_name"]["is_insured"] = name["is_insured"]

    newdict["DEPENDENTS"] = innerdict

    return newdict

for name in names:
    if name["name"] in results.keys():
        dname = name["dep_name"]
        is_minor = name["is_dep_minor"]
        is_insured = name["is_dep_insured"]

        name = results.get(name["name"])
        name["DEPENDENT"][dname]["is_dep_minor"] = is_minor
        name["DEPENDENT"][dname]["is_dep_insured"] = is_insured
    else:
        newdict = create_dict()
        results[name["name"]] = newdict
```

This thing gives the desired output